# R Extract digit from name of elements in a List and insert extracted number into each element as new column

Tags: r

I have a list of several DataFrames and each dataframes has names like puri9_raw, puri10_raw etc.

I like to extract the numbers in the names eg. 9, 10, 11...
and insert these digit in each respective dataframes as a new columns.

I wrote a function to do this and was thinking to use lapply() to do this but I'm getting error.
When I apply this function on a Dataframe directly it works:

```
addcategory <- function(df) {
  df$category <- str_extract(as.character(substitute(df)), "\\d+")
  return(df)
}

newdf <- addcategory(pur9)
```

Performing this function in lapply():

```
a <- lapply(filtered_files, addcategory)
```

it return the below error instead:

```
 Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "category", value = c(NA_character_,  : 
  replacement has 3 rows, data has 32
```

Appreciate your help!

**data of filtered_files**

```
structure(list(purifier10corr_cleaned = structure(list(x = c("Inlet Gas Pressure", 
"Inlet Gas Pressure", "Inlet Gas Pressure", "Inlet Gas Pressure", 
"Outlet Gas Pressure", "Total Purified Time (Lower)", "Total Purified Time (Lower)", 
"Total Purified Time (Lower)", "Total Purified Time (Lower)", 
"Total Purified Time (Lower)", "Total Purified Time (Lower)", 
"Total Purified Time (Lower)", "Vessel A Flow Rate", "Vessel A Flow Rate", 
"Vessel A Flow Rate", "Vessel A Flow Rate", "Vessel A Flow Rate", 
"Vessel A Flow Rate", "TC1A PH Wall", "TC1A PH Wall", "TC1A PH Wall", 
"TC1A PH Wall", "TC2A Vessel Bed", "TC2A Vessel Bed", "TC2A Vessel Bed", 
"TC2A Vessel Bed", "TC3A Vessel Wall", "TC3A Vessel Wall", "TC3A Vessel Wall", 
"GS1A Gettsafe", "GS1A Gettsafe", "Vessel A Preheater Output"
), y = c("Outlet Gas Pressure", "Total Purified Time (Lower)", 
"Vessel A Flow Total (Lower)", "Delta P Pressure", "Vessel A Flow Total (Lower)", 
"Vessel A Flow Rate", "TC1A PH Wall", "TC2A Vessel Bed", "TC3A Vessel Wall", 
"GS1A Gettsafe", "Vessel A Preheater Output", "Delta P Pressure", 
"TC1A PH Wall", "TC2A Vessel Bed", "TC3A Vessel Wall", "GS1A Gettsafe", 
"Vessel A Preheater Output", "Delta P Pressure", "TC2A Vessel Bed", 
"GS1A Gettsafe", "Vessel A Preheater Output", "Delta P Pressure", 
"TC3A Vessel Wall", "GS1A Gettsafe", "Vessel A Preheater Output", 
"Delta P Pressure", "GS1A Gettsafe", "Vessel A Preheater Output", 
"Delta P Pressure", "Vessel A Preheater Output", "Delta P Pressure", 
"Delta P Pressure"), cdf = c(0.942582844653833, 0.851312566463532, 
0.74618899263432, 0.73339384226807, 0.700802927079407, 0.92942206712539, 
0.852259766192025, -0.842065919341967, -0.803131063975672, -0.790831106388823, 
0.919210668235385, 0.936387965341553, 0.892034573246212, -0.952737592363305, 
-0.871547177967677, -0.931920970063449, 0.987797574517254, 0.960376852857353, 
-0.736326946302192, -0.720754247510457, 0.865945105089496, 0.873417284945245, 
0.960368610704985, 0.991031231534187, -0.956051607303599, -0.894230230210303, 
0.946168658653559, -0.875438872772781, -0.829627717387136, -0.931190098160053, 
-0.861839580799302, 0.949959380849764), abscorr = c(0.942582844653833, 
0.851312566463532, 0.74618899263432, 0.73339384226807, 0.700802927079407, 
0.92942206712539, 0.852259766192025, 0.842065919341967, 0.803131063975672, 
0.790831106388823, 0.919210668235385, 0.936387965341553, 0.892034573246212, 
0.952737592363305, 0.871547177967677, 0.931920970063449, 0.987797574517254, 
0.960376852857353, 0.736326946302192, 0.720754247510457, 0.865945105089496, 
0.873417284945245, 0.960368610704985, 0.991031231534187, 0.956051607303599, 
0.894230230210303, 0.946168658653559, 0.875438872772781, 0.829627717387136, 
0.931190098160053, 0.861839580799302, 0.949959380849764)), .Names = c("x", 
"y", "cdf", "abscorr"), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 4L, 11L, 16L, 26L, 
28L, 29L, 30L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 56L, 
59L, 60L, 61L, 64L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 72L, 73L, 74L, 82L, 83L, 86L
), class = "data.frame"), purifier11corr_cleaned = structure(list(
    x = c("Inlet Gas Pressure", "Inlet Gas Pressure", "Inlet Gas Pressure", 
    "Inlet Gas Pressure", "Inlet Gas Pressure", "Inlet Gas Pressure", 
    "Inlet Gas Pressure", "Outlet Gas Pressure", "Total Purified Time (Lower)", 
    "Total Purified Time (Lower)", "Total Purified Time (Lower)", 
    "Total Purified Time (Lower)", "Total Purified Time (Lower)", 
    "Total Purified Time (Lower)", "Vessel A Flow Rate", "Vessel A Flow Rate", 
    "Vessel A Flow Rate", "Vessel A Flow Rate", "TC1A PH Wall", 
    "TC1A PH Wall", "TC1A PH Wall", "TC3A Vessel Wall", "TC3A Vessel Wall", 
    "Vessel A Preheater Output"), y = c("Outlet Gas Pressure", 
    "Total Purified Time (Lower)", "Vessel A Flow Rate", "Vessel A Flow Total (Lower)", 
    "TC2A Vessel Bed", "Vessel A Preheater Output", "Delta P Pressure", 
    "Vessel A Flow Total (Lower)", "Vessel A Flow Rate", "TC1A PH Wall", 
    "TC2A Vessel Bed", "TC3A Vessel Wall", "Vessel A Preheater Output", 
    "Delta P Pressure", "TC1A PH Wall", "TC3A Vessel Wall", "Vessel A Preheater Output", 
    "Delta P Pressure", "TC3A Vessel Wall", "Vessel A Preheater Output", 
    "Delta P Pressure", "Vessel A Preheater Output", "Delta P Pressure", 
    "Delta P Pressure"), cdf = c(0.895030043596337, 0.867471044291586, 
    0.726872575365218, 0.760362626995556, 0.743348278242154, 
    0.712935126800633, 0.704984735450192, 0.738844433701125, 
    0.929132059555132, 0.905268959512924, 0.77556658970724, 0.875487957528081, 
    0.912746096128495, 0.913144763303326, 0.993278221439425, 
    0.980285529550282, 0.990499518758699, 0.973842952423053, 
    0.988818078882709, 0.987155661086668, 0.972628468744456, 
    0.986111031922197, 0.94878802373624, 0.960097382317158), 
    abscorr = c(0.895030043596337, 0.867471044291586, 0.726872575365218, 
    0.760362626995556, 0.743348278242154, 0.712935126800633, 
    0.704984735450192, 0.738844433701125, 0.929132059555132, 
    0.905268959512924, 0.77556658970724, 0.875487957528081, 0.912746096128495, 
    0.913144763303326, 0.993278221439425, 0.980285529550282, 
    0.990499518758699, 0.973842952423053, 0.988818078882709, 
    0.987155661086668, 0.972628468744456, 0.986111031922197, 
    0.94878802373624, 0.960097382317158)), .Names = c("x", "y", 
"cdf", "abscorr"), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 10L, 11L, 
16L, 26L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 33L, 34L, 38L, 40L, 43L, 44L, 57L, 60L, 
61L, 73L, 74L, 86L), class = "data.frame"), purifier12corr_cleaned = structure(list(
    x = c("Inlet Gas Pressure", "Inlet Gas Pressure", "Inlet Gas Pressure", 
    "Inlet Gas Pressure", "Inlet Gas Pressure", "Inlet Gas Pressure", 
    "Inlet Gas Pressure", "Outlet Gas Pressure", "Total Purified Time (Lower)", 
    "Total Purified Time (Lower)", "Total Purified Time (Lower)", 
    "Total Purified Time (Lower)", "Total Purified Time (Lower)", 
    "Total Purified Time (Lower)", "Vessel A Flow Rate", "Vessel A Flow Rate", 
    "Vessel A Flow Rate", "Vessel A Flow Rate", "Vessel A Flow Rate", 
    "Vessel A Flow Rate", "Vessel A Flow Rate", "TC1A PH Wall", 
    "TC1A PH Wall", "TC1A PH Wall", "TC1A PH Wall", "TC1A PH Wall", 
    "TC1A PH Wall", "TC2A Vessel Bed", "TC2A Vessel Bed", "TC2A Vessel Bed", 
    "TC2A Vessel Bed", "TC3A Vessel Wall", "TC3A Vessel Wall", 
    "TC3A Vessel Wall", "TC3A Vessel Wall", "TC4A Outlet Gas", 
    "TC4A Outlet Gas", "Vessel A Preheater Output", "Vessel A Preheater Output", 
    "Vessel A Blanket Output"), y = c("Outlet Gas Pressure", 
    "Total Purified Time (Lower)", "Vessel A Flow Rate", "Vessel A Flow Total (Lower)", 
    "Vessel A Preheater Output", "Vessel A Blanket Output", "Delta P Pressure", 
    "Vessel A Flow Total (Lower)", "Vessel A Flow Rate", "TC1A PH Wall", 
    "TC3A Vessel Wall", "Vessel A Preheater Output", "Vessel A Blanket Output", 
    "Delta P Pressure", "TC1A PH Wall", "TC2A Vessel Bed", "TC3A Vessel Wall", 
    "TC4A Outlet Gas", "Vessel A Preheater Output", "Vessel A Blanket Output", 
    "Delta P Pressure", "TC2A Vessel Bed", "TC3A Vessel Wall", 
    "TC4A Outlet Gas", "Vessel A Preheater Output", "Vessel A Blanket Output", 
    "Delta P Pressure", "TC3A Vessel Wall", "GS1A Gettsafe", 
    "Vessel A Preheater Output", "Delta P Pressure", "TC4A Outlet Gas", 
    "Vessel A Preheater Output", "Vessel A Blanket Output", "Delta P Pressure", 
    "Vessel A Preheater Output", "Delta P Pressure", "Vessel A Blanket Output", 
    "Delta P Pressure", "Delta P Pressure"), cdf = c(0.926850587663412, 
    0.866691836294412, 0.769005792434557, 0.734786596246863, 
    0.765617383853654, 0.737339049196957, 0.772607862034451, 
    0.702819738672892, 0.954381581275433, 0.927932921277022, 
    0.927625508556892, 0.954311120176031, 0.832869757257207, 
    0.941592261478602, 0.98686719856886, -0.777935212612154, 
    0.985980225682492, 0.747897353936776, 0.990115955814871, 
    0.831400479370571, 0.969063553912319, -0.768460373541157, 
    0.999345357812714, 0.795470208694951, 0.979958754192373, 
    0.786061475983542, 0.957361626888298, -0.765969157221048, 
    0.853635545501843, -0.783155248265995, -0.717281138076634, 
    0.795066039607157, 0.978992788697791, 0.780304181320046, 
    0.956497329457768, 0.73007053107914, 0.724580339277283, 0.843696945250939, 
    0.962553775738599, 0.80743766860876), abscorr = c(0.926850587663412, 
    0.866691836294412, 0.769005792434557, 0.734786596246863, 
    0.765617383853654, 0.737339049196957, 0.772607862034451, 
    0.702819738672892, 0.954381581275433, 0.927932921277022, 
    0.927625508556892, 0.954311120176031, 0.832869757257207, 
    0.941592261478602, 0.98686719856886, 0.777935212612154, 0.985980225682492, 
    0.747897353936776, 0.990115955814871, 0.831400479370571, 
    0.969063553912319, 0.768460373541157, 0.999345357812714, 
    0.795470208694951, 0.979958754192373, 0.786061475983542, 
    0.957361626888298, 0.765969157221048, 0.853635545501843, 
    0.783155248265995, 0.717281138076634, 0.795066039607157, 
    0.978992788697791, 0.780304181320046, 0.956497329457768, 
    0.73007053107914, 0.724580339277283, 0.843696945250939, 0.962553775738599, 
    0.80743766860876)), .Names = c("x", "y", "cdf", "abscorr"
), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 17L, 28L, 30L, 
32L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 61L, 62L, 
63L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 70L, 72L, 73L, 75L, 78L, 80L, 81L, 82L, 86L, 
88L, 96L, 97L, 100L), class = "data.frame"), purifier14corr_cleaned = structure(list(
    x = c("Inlet Gas Pressure", "Total Purified Time (Lower)", 
    "Total Purified Time (Lower)", "Total Purified Time (Lower)", 
    "Total Purified Time (Lower)", "Total Purified Time (Lower)", 
    "Total Purified Time (Lower)", "Total Purified Time (Lower)", 
    "Total Purified Time (Lower)", "Vessel A Flow Rate", "Vessel A Flow Rate", 
    "Vessel A Flow Rate", "Vessel A Flow Rate", "Vessel A Flow Rate", 
    "Vessel A Flow Total (Lower)", "Vessel A Flow Total (Lower)", 
    "Vessel A Flow Total (Lower)", "Vessel A Flow Total (Lower)", 
    "Vessel A Flow Total (Lower)", "Vessel A Flow Total (Lower)", 
    "TC1A PH Wall", "TC1A PH Wall", "TC1A PH Wall", "TC2A Vessel Bed", 
    "TC2A Vessel Bed", "TC2A Vessel Bed", "GS1A Gettsafe", "GS1A Gettsafe", 
    "Vessel A Preheater Output"), y = c("Outlet Gas Pressure", 
    "Vessel A Flow Rate", "Vessel A Flow Total (Lower)", "TC1A PH Wall", 
    "TC2A Vessel Bed", "TC3A Vessel Wall", "GS1A Gettsafe", "Vessel A Preheater Output", 
    "Vessel A Blanket Output", "Vessel A Flow Total (Lower)", 
    "TC2A Vessel Bed", "GS1A Gettsafe", "Vessel A Preheater Output", 
    "Vessel A Blanket Output", "TC1A PH Wall", "TC2A Vessel Bed", 
    "TC3A Vessel Wall", "GS1A Gettsafe", "Vessel A Preheater Output", 
    "Vessel A Blanket Output", "TC3A Vessel Wall", "Vessel A Preheater Output", 
    "Vessel A Blanket Output", "GS1A Gettsafe", "Vessel A Preheater Output", 
    "Vessel A Blanket Output", "Vessel A Preheater Output", "Vessel A Blanket Output", 
    "Vessel A Blanket Output"), cdf = c(0.928682218151924, -0.716165706235164, 
    0.996983042088941, 0.942533565718294, -0.82106928127015, 
    0.868507408828244, -0.721102791716829, -0.883320615741987, 
    0.90771354030701, -0.740946425296549, 0.803456554526274, 
    0.777725649353059, 0.818157508787532, -0.817160358197827, 
    0.91972091493354, -0.858904626399683, 0.847609637376188, 
    -0.76840092768087, -0.909805769757979, 0.93435361657217, 
    0.927543426719748, -0.72114256731816, 0.747217151788518, 
    0.973149191226473, 0.956891100840945, -0.974582912452621, 
    0.912622326854633, -0.929743555493146, -0.976861022325206
    ), abscorr = c(0.928682218151924, 0.716165706235164, 0.996983042088941, 
    0.942533565718294, 0.82106928127015, 0.868507408828244, 0.721102791716829, 
    0.883320615741987, 0.90771354030701, 0.740946425296549, 0.803456554526274, 
    0.777725649353059, 0.818157508787532, 0.817160358197827, 
    0.91972091493354, 0.858904626399683, 0.847609637376188, 0.76840092768087, 
    0.909805769757979, 0.93435361657217, 0.927543426719748, 0.72114256731816, 
    0.747217151788518, 0.973149191226473, 0.956891100840945, 
    0.974582912452621, 0.912622326854633, 0.929743555493146, 
    0.976861022325206)), .Names = c("x", "y", "cdf", "abscorr"
), row.names = c(1L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 
40L, 42L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 62L, 65L, 
66L, 72L, 73L, 74L, 91L, 92L, 96L), class = "data.frame"), purifier15corr_cleaned = structure(list(
    x = c("Inlet Gas Pressure", "Total Purified Time (Lower)"
    ), y = c("Outlet Gas Pressure", "Vessel A Flow Total (Lower)"
    ), cdf = c(0.81775813622335, 0.999669773826533), abscorr = c(0.81775813622335, 
    0.999669773826533)), .Names = c("x", "y", "cdf", "abscorr"
), row.names = c(1L, 29L), class = "data.frame"), purifier9corr_cleaned = structure(list(
    x = c("Inlet Gas Pressure", "Inlet Gas Pressure", "Inlet Gas Pressure", 
    "Inlet Gas Pressure", "Inlet Gas Pressure", "Inlet Gas Pressure", 
    "Inlet Gas Pressure", "Inlet Gas Pressure", "Outlet Gas Pressure", 
    "Total Purified Time (Lower)", "Total Purified Time (Lower)", 
    "Total Purified Time (Lower)", "Total Purified Time (Lower)", 
    "Total Purified Time (Lower)", "Vessel A Flow Rate", "Vessel A Flow Rate", 
    "Vessel A Flow Rate", "Vessel A Flow Rate", "Vessel A Flow Rate", 
    "TC1A PH Wall", "TC1A PH Wall", "TC1A PH Wall", "TC1A PH Wall", 
    "TC2A Vessel Bed", "TC3A Vessel Wall", "TC3A Vessel Wall", 
    "TC3A Vessel Wall", "TC4A Outlet Gas", "TC4A Outlet Gas", 
    "Vessel A Preheater Output"), y = c("Outlet Gas Pressure", 
    "Total Purified Time (Lower)", "Vessel A Flow Rate", "Vessel A Flow Total (Lower)", 
    "TC1A PH Wall", "TC3A Vessel Wall", "Vessel A Preheater Output", 
    "Delta P Pressure", "Vessel A Flow Total (Lower)", "Vessel A Flow Rate", 
    "TC1A PH Wall", "TC3A Vessel Wall", "Vessel A Preheater Output", 
    "Delta P Pressure", "TC1A PH Wall", "TC3A Vessel Wall", "TC4A Outlet Gas", 
    "Vessel A Preheater Output", "Delta P Pressure", "TC3A Vessel Wall", 
    "TC4A Outlet Gas", "Vessel A Preheater Output", "Delta P Pressure", 
    "GS1A Gettsafe", "TC4A Outlet Gas", "Vessel A Preheater Output", 
    "Delta P Pressure", "Vessel A Preheater Output", "Delta P Pressure", 
    "Delta P Pressure"), cdf = c(0.944604888321056, 0.874809845503791, 
    0.762637074418356, 0.732835271617901, 0.711272965227059, 
    0.709910624822269, 0.735953626590443, 0.767828174551441, 
    0.71020200631915, 0.943973621052222, 0.926500529073283, 0.925352060360054, 
    0.925566182218301, 0.935238128128665, 0.989077927174152, 
    0.985729070305404, 0.729464824402568, 0.986236284898409, 
    0.968901353422607, 0.996662300785658, 0.780312177585249, 
    0.9784098562977, 0.962592819382886, 0.811616937725951, 0.780733881483196, 
    0.977377106827236, 0.956604872098185, 0.725293982642169, 
    0.702186452815522, 0.953496206415149), abscorr = c(0.944604888321056, 
    0.874809845503791, 0.762637074418356, 0.732835271617901, 
    0.711272965227059, 0.709910624822269, 0.735953626590443, 
    0.767828174551441, 0.71020200631915, 0.943973621052222, 0.926500529073283, 
    0.925352060360054, 0.925566182218301, 0.935238128128665, 
    0.989077927174152, 0.985729070305404, 0.729464824402568, 
    0.986236284898409, 0.968901353422607, 0.996662300785658, 
    0.780312177585249, 0.9784098562977, 0.962592819382886, 0.811616937725951, 
    0.780733881483196, 0.977377106827236, 0.956604872098185, 
    0.725293982642169, 0.702186452815522, 0.953496206415149)), .Names = c("x", 
"y", "cdf", "abscorr"), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 
10L, 11L, 16L, 26L, 28L, 30L, 33L, 34L, 38L, 40L, 41L, 43L, 44L, 
57L, 58L, 60L, 61L, 66L, 71L, 73L, 74L, 78L, 79L, 86L), class = "data.frame")), .Names = c("purifier10corr_cleaned", 
"purifier11corr_cleaned", "purifier12corr_cleaned", "purifier14corr_cleaned", 
"purifier15corr_cleaned", "purifier9corr_cleaned"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just run a loop across the elements of the list, as below:

```
for (i in seq_along(filtered_files)) {
  filtered_files[[i]]$category <- stringr::str_extract(names(filtered_files)[i], "\\d+")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass name and dataframe as two arguments to the function.

```
addcategory <- function(df, name) {
  df$category <- stringr::str_extract(name, "\\d+")
  return(df)
}
```

Then you can use `purrr::imap`

```
filtered_files  <- purrr::imap(filtered_files, addcategory)
```

Or base R `Map`

```
filtered_files  <- Map(addcategory, filtered_files, names(filtered_files))
```